# TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, scikit-learn, data-cleaning

The following code is supposed to encode categorical data, but it is throwing an error. X is a matrix consisting of 3 columns where the first column (index 0) is a categorical variable, which I am trying to one-hot-encode. Thanks!

```
#Importing dataset 

#Importing csv with pandas
dataset = pd.read_csv("Data.csv")

#Creating our matrix of independent variables (X)
X = dataset.iloc[:, :-1].values

#Creating the dependent variable vector (y)
y = dataset.iloc[:, 3]
```

Missing values

```
#Dealing with missing values 

#import Imputer class from sklearn 
from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer

#create an object from the Imputer class
imputer = Imputer(missing_values = "NaN", strategy = 'mean')

#fit 'imputer' object to our independent variable matrix X 
imputer.fit(X[:, 1:3])

#Updating our matrix X using transform method
X[:, 1:3] = imputer.transform(X[:, 1:3])
```

One hot coding

```
#import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder classes from sklearn 
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder

#create an object from the LabelEncoder class 
labelencoder_X = LabelEncoder()

#update our matrix X with encoded values 
X[:, 0] = labelencoder_X.fit_transform(X[:, 0])

#create an object from OneHotEncoder class 
onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = [0])

#fit 'onehotencoder' object to our first column
X = onehotencoder.fit_transform(X).toarray()
```

Error (in One hot encoding):

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-58-2a8dcc36489d> in <module>()
      8 
      9 #update our matrix X with encoded values
---> 10 X[:, 0] = labelencoder_X.fit_transform(X[:, 0])
     11 
     12 #create an object from OneHotEncoder class

TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Are you sure `X` is a matrix? How did you create X?

Comment: Can you provide the definition of X?

Comment: You haven't shown us what `X` is, but apparently it's a method.

Comment: You added an entire code snippet but took out the root of the problem.

Comment: sorry guys, updated

Comment: @novice Are you sure `dataset...values` is a field, not a method? Maybe it should be `dataset...values()`?

Comment: @Carcigenicate Strange, it's working now, thanks!

Comment: @Carcigenicate `values`  is an attribute of `pd.DataFrame`  which returns from `pd.read_csv`. It is not a method. I believe the problem is something else.

Comment: @ayhan That's why I asked. I've never used DataFrames before.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Maybe it's working because I ran the entire program again? Happens sometimes. Although your solution does make sense